# Controle de acesso Access-Control-Allow-Origin no lado servidor Apache PHP

Tags: php, api, apache, htaccess

Não entendo muito de PHP e estou tentando criar um aplicativo para cadastrar automaticamente os produtos da minha loja virtual diretamente no MercadoLivre.

Os dados do anuncio são capturados com `JavaScript` e enviados para a API do ML via `$.ajax`, o que acontece é que as imagens que são passadas somente a URL para a API não estão subindo para o site, conferi as URLs e estão corretas.

Tentei setar a URL da logo do site (que é menor) e mesmo assim não vai (não recebo nenhum retorno da API se a imagem foi ou não, ela só não aparece no anuncio).
Se eu pego a URL de uma imagem de outro site (peguei uma do Wikipedia), ela sobe corretamente.

A loja virtual é em PHP  (Opencart) no servidor Apache, será que este bloqueio pode estar ocorrendo no lado servidor pelo PHP ou Apache?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver desativando o "Always use HTTPS" do CloudFlare.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é um tipo de bloqueio que ocorre no servidor da aplicação você pode contornado enviando um herdade que aceita todas as origens

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Muito importante que isso seja chamado antes de qualquer outra coisa

**Errado**

```
<html>
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
?>
```

**Correto**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
?>
<html>
```

Comment: Mas como a API do ML vai requisitar diretamente o arquivo JPG, onde eu posso inserir este código?